# Combine multiple paired data frames from two lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I want comebine data frames from two lists with the same name, and delete all repeated rows in each data frame after binding. I have tried the package `'pylr'`, but it doesn't seem work.
The data frames all have the same length as follows:

```
> summary(ww)
         Length Class      Mode
WFGC01  19     data.frame list
WFGC02  19     data.frame list
WFGC03  19     data.frame list
WFGC05  19     data.frame list
WFGC09  19     data.frame list
WFGC10  19     data.frame list
WFGC13  19     data.frame list
WFGC15  19     data.frame list
WFGC17  19     data.frame list
WFGC18  19     data.frame list
WFGC19  19     data.frame list
WFGC20  19     data.frame list
WFGC21  19     data.frame list
WFGC22  19     data.frame list
```

and

```
 > summary(dd03)
       Length Class      Mode
WFGC02 19     data.frame list
WFGC03 19     data.frame list
WFGC05 19     data.frame list
WFGC07 19     data.frame list
WFGC10 19     data.frame list
WFGC13 19     data.frame list
WFGC17 19     data.frame list
WFGC18 19     data.frame list
WFGC22 19     data.frame list
WFGC24 19     data.frame list
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet of what you've tried?

Comment: do you mean `rbindlist` and then `unique`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the explanation of your problem, the following may work:

```
# get all overlapping names
bindNames <- intersect(names(ww), names(dd03))
# get a list of rbinded data.frames, keeping unique observations
newList <- lapply(bindNames, function(i) unique(rbind(ww[[i]], dd03[[i]])))
```

If at this point, you want to append all of your data.frames into a single data.frame, you can once again use `lapply`.

```
newDataFrame <- as.data.frame(lapply(newList, rbind))
```

Comment: I humbly think if you show taking newList to data.frame you get Yann home for the moment.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. I wasn't sure if the OP wanted a list of appended data.frame or one single large data.frame, but it wouldn't hurt to show how to get larger data.frame.

Comment: @Imo Thank you so much! I just need this. It really helped a lot.