# How to make a complex list into a dataframe in R?

Tags: json, r, list

I have a complex list which is get from a json file.

The json file was get from a map service api in China.

I searched the website to solve the problem but I can't find a proper solution to my question, so I put it in this question and hope it can be solved.

If I missing something that I didn't find in the website, I apologize for that.

The code to get the  list are as follows:`

```
library(rjson)    
library(RCurl)    
key<-"fd5a14632c36aecd2e759a0cc91a3b4a"   

origin<-"大润发东环店"

urlorigin <- paste("http://restapi.amap.com/v3/geocode/geo?key=",key,"&address=",origin,"&city=苏州",sep = "")    
dataorigin<-readLines(urlorigin,encoding="UTF-8")   
origininfo<-fromJSON(dataorigin)   
originpoi<-origininfo$geocodes[[1]]$location 
destination<-"苏州大学本部北门"    
urldest <- paste("http://restapi.amap.com/v3/geocode/geo?key=",key,"&address=",destination,"&city=苏州",sep = "")    
datadest<-readLines(urldest,encoding="UTF-8")    
destinfo<-fromJSON(datadest)    
destpoi<-destinfo$geocodes[[1]]$location

urlpath <- paste("http://restapi.amap.com/v3/direction/driving?key=",key,"&origin=",originpoi,"&destination=",destpoi,           "&originid=&destinationid=&extensions=all&strategy=0&waypoints=&avoidpolygons=&avoidroad=",sep = "")   
pathjson<-paste(readLines(urlpath,encoding = "UTF-8"),collapse = "")   
pathinfo<-fromJSON(pathjson)
```

The `pathinfo` was the list I get at last and I want to convert it into a dataframe that I can work with.

Thank you for your time.

I'm from China and my English is not that good, I apologize for that.

Comment: what is the  expected `data.frame` structure?

Comment: newDataFrame <- as.data.frame(lapply(newList, rbind)) , from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649525/combine-multiple-paired-data-frames-from-two-lists/36649810)

Comment: Please include the expected output into your question.

Answer (score 0):

My Chinese is very limited as well. But your code to get the data is working (with some warnings).

```
pathinfo_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(pathinfo,rbind))
```

pathinfo_df is now a data_frame.

```
summary(pathinfo_df)
status info    infocode count
1:1    OK:1   10000:1   1:1  
route.origin.Length  route.origin.Class  route.origin.Mode
1          -none-     character                           
 route.destination.Length  route.destination.Class  route.destination.Mode
1          -none-     character                                          
route.taxi_cost.Length  route.taxi_cost.Class  route.taxi_cost.Mode
1          -none-     character                                    
route.paths.Length  route.paths.Class  route.paths.Mode
1       -none-  list
```

So, there's plenty to select and play with. Read up on selecting from lists. see also:

```
str(pathinfo_df)
```

Then map it on Google Earth. Looks like the taxi might be costly. Have a good trip!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solves some of my problem.But I want more information about this list.